# ListFragment onCreateView not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to use a FragmentManager to replace a fragment but for some reason the `OnCreateView()` isn't called.

This is the code I use to create the fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FeedbackListFragment listFragment = new FeedbackListFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.feedback_placeholder, listFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This is the code for FeedbackListFragment:

```
public class FeedbackListFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"create feedbacklistview");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedback_popup, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/background_normal"
              android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/feedback_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/overview_scan_text"
            android:id="@+id/scantagLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:id="@+id/cleanjack_image"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_clean_jack"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/messageLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've removed the `android:visibility="gone"` to see if that was the issue but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your Sample code

Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    FeedbackListFragment listFragment = new FeedbackListFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.feedback_placeholder, listFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

FragmentList :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedback_popup, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

XML Activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bcbcbc"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/feedback_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="overview_scan_text"
        android:id="@+id/scantagLabel"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/cleanjack_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/messageLabel"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Xml Fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView

        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Have you set the id of listView of fragmentList to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't want the fragment to be created in the onCreate I need to switch to the fragment when something happens. Should I be doing it differently then?

Comment: No, i juste add the creation of fragment in onCreate for general cases, but you can do it in interaction with button or what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for onCreateView in ListFragment:

> Provide default implementation to return a simple list view.  Subclasses
>        can override to replace with their own layout.  If doing so, the
>        returned view hierarchy *must* have a ListView whose id
>        is {@link android.R.id#list android.R.id.list} and can optionally
>        have a sibling view id {@link android.R.id#empty android.R.id.empty}
>        that is to be shown when the list is empty.
>
> If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
>         consider including the standard layout {@link android.R.layout#list_content}
>         in your layout file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard
>         behavior of ListFragment.  In particular, this is currently the only
>         way to have the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.

Comment: I've given the listview the id list but still no luck.